# CSV file removing brackets, quotation marks, and u in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am updating my csv file (can be found at `https://www.kaggle.com/carolzhangdc/imdb-5000-movie-dataset`) and it's not updating my csv file as expected.

below is my code

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

with open('movie_metadata.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            row.append("movie_links")
            print('Column names are {}'.format(", ".join(row)))
            line_count += 1
        else:
            imdb_link = row[17]
            soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(imdb_link).read(), features="html.parser")
            link = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'poster'})
            if link:
                print(link[0].find('img')['src'])
                row.append(link[0].find('img')['src'])
            line_count += 1
        with open('movie.csv', 'wb') as writeFile:
            writer = csv.writer(writeFile, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow([str(row)])


    print('Processed {} lines.'.format(line_count))
```

I want to update my csv as the following format

```
Color,James Cameron,723,178,0,855,Joel David Moore,1000,760505847,Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi,CCH Pounder,Avatar ,886204,4834,Wes Studi,0,avatar|future|marine|native|paraplegic,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1,3054,English,USA,PG-13,237000000,2009,936,7.9,1.78,33000,1,https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjIyNjkxNzEyMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjc3MDE3._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg
```

but it formats it as follows

```
"['Color', 'Gore Verbinski', '302', '169', '563', '1000', 'Orlando Bloom', '40000', '309404152', 'Action|Adventure|Fantasy', 'Johnny Depp', ""Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End\xc2\xa0"", '471220', '48350', 'Jack Davenport', '0', 'goddess|marriage ceremony|marriage proposal|pirate|singapore', 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0449088/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1', '1238', 'English', 'USA', 'PG-13', '300000000', '2007', '5000', '7.1', '2.35', '0', '2', u'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjIyNjkxNzEyMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjc3MDE3._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg']"
```

why does it add brackets `[]` and quotation marks as well as `u'` in front of my last element?

Comment: you are passing a string to the writer. have you tried just passing the row. `writer.writerow(row)`

Comment: You are pasing a list of your row converted to string ... **writer.writerow([str(row)])**. Remove the [] and the str and use writer.writerow(row) as @ChrisDoyle said

Answer (score 1):

Jaoa , just done a few modifications to your code

- First strip the img src that is found upstream from imdb usind `strip()`
- Combine all the rows to a tracking list `all_rows` and write them once after the for loop ends
- The call you had on the csvwriter was not getting the right file object type ,I've updated that to use the write mode `open('file', 'w')`

You have to note that since the movie link has commas, `,` it must be quoted using `"` by the csv module in python so as not to 'confuse' csv applications , hence you can't avoid that.

I've also added some print statements which you can remove.

```
# coding: utf-8
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib


def reader(movies_file, target_file):
    with open(movies_file) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        line_count = 0
        all_rows = []

        for row in csv_reader:
            if line_count == 0:
                row.append("movie_links")
                print('Column names are {}'.format(", ".join(row)))
                line_count += 1
            else:
                print("Going into the rows")
                imdb_link = row[17]
                print("LInk for the row is ", imdb_link)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(imdb_link).read(),
                                     features="html.parser")
                link = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'poster'})
                if link:
                    print(link[0].find('img')['src'])
                    row.append(link[0].find('img')['src'].strip(''))
                line_count += 1
                all_rows.append(row)
    with open(target_file, 'w') as writeFile:
        writer = csv.writer(writeFile, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(all_rows)
```

Call the function like , and your desired content will be in movie.csv file

```
>>> reader('movie_data.csv', 'movie.csv')
```

NB. this is python 3.7.

The `u` in the strings means this is a unicode string so that should not be an issue , you can call `str(img_src)` to remove the `u`.